# Digital Hall sensor only connects to ground when active

Tags: power-supply, mosfet, battery-operated, hall-effect

I want to make a power control circuit that turns off when a digital hall sensor detects a magnet.
All digital hall sensors I have found connect to ground when active. I was thinking about using a depletion type mosfet, but they don't come in p-type.

[image: My not so good circuit]

Comment: Going to need to see a part number and datasheet for that hall sensor. Also, Vcc is usually placed up and GND down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just invert the open drain output of your sensor with a BJT:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgnipA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you! what specs would be important for Q1? do you have a smd part you recommend?

Comment: @OpticalOpal Any NPN will work here, BC847B is the SMD version of Q1.